# Использование файлов .properties с нестандартной кодировкой (не ISO 8859-1)

Tags: java, spring

Страница не показывает русские символы вместо русских символов показывает вопросы, 
текст берется из mesages_ru.properties, если написать русский текст напрямую в jsp странице она их отображает правильно
настроено как я понял правильно

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
только вот в файле properties внизу где написано тип кодировки написано Windows-1251 который не меняется и при наведении на него пишет File encoding is disabled .properties file в чем дело

Comment: Ну могу предложить открыть файл в каком-нибудь notepad и поменять там кодировку. Или можно еще [тут](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-encoding-for-properties-files.html) прочитать

Answer (score 11, accepted):

В Idea кодировка для .properties файлов задается по особому и делается это на уровне проекта:

> Стандартное Java API спроектировано для использования ISO 8859-1 для properties файлов.
>
> Чтобы использовать другие кодировки, можно использовать управляющие последовательности и Unicode (виде \uXXXX, например \u0410 = русская А). Альтернатива - определить кодировку по умолчанию для файлов .properties на уровне проекта и использовать другое API, которое может читать файлы настроек в заданной кодировке.
>
> Кодировка для файла настроек задается следующим образом
>
> 1. Открыть диалоговое окно Settings и выбрать File Encodings.
> 2. Сделать одно из следующего:
>
>    - Чтобы включить специальный режим, когда символы сохраняются в файле как управляющие последовательности, но отображаются как нормальные буквы, выберите ***Transparent native-to-ascii conversion***. Эта опция полезна когда файлы настройки закодированы в ISO 8859-1. Рекомендуется использовать этот способ, если у вас нет особых причин менять кодировку.
>    - В поле ***Default encoding for properties files***, выберите кодировку, которую вы хотите использовать для всех файлов настройки в проекте.

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-encoding-for-properties-files.html

Comment: Помогло, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

я использую файлы .xml вместо .properties, так же задаются пары ключ/значение.
Проблем с кодировкой вообще не возникает.
Пример содержимого файла:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<!--файл конфигурации -->
<properties>
    <!-- режим отладки -->
    <entry key="debug">false</entry>
    <!-- еще какое то свойство -->
    <entry key="myKey">valueMyKey</entry>
</properties>
```